# vcpkg install fails with "SSL connect error"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, vcpkg

When I try to install libxml2 packages with vcpkg, it gives me below error.

How can overcome this issue? Is there a way to use http instead of https in vcpkg? Or can I skipp sll check?

> .\vcpkg install libxml2
>
> The following packages will be built and installed:
>
> - libiconv:x86-windows
> - liblzma:x86-windows
> - libxml2:x86-windows
> - zlib:x86-windows
>
> Additional packages (*) will be installed to complete this operation.
>
> Starting package 1/4: zlib:x86-windows
>
> Building package zlib:x86-windows...
>
> -- CURRENT_INSTALLED_DIR=...
>
> -- Downloading http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz...
>
> -- Downloading http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz... Failed. Status: 56;"Failure when receiving data from the peer"
>
> -- Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.11/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz...
>
> -- Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.11/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz... Failed. Status: 35;"SSL connect error"
>
> CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:82 (message): Failed to download file. Add mirrors or submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):  ports/zlib/portfile.cmake:3 (vcpkg_download_distfile) scripts/ports.cmake:72 (include)
>
> Error: Building package zlib:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this problem by editing `profile.cmake` file in `vcpkg\ports\libxml2\` folder. I added ftp link `URLS "ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz"` and vcpkg downloaded files over ftp.